# Forward application log to windows Event log

Tags: powershell

I want to create a new EventLog for an application running on my server and the log should be taken from the default log file of the application.

Any idea on how to achieve this??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean event source?
PowerShell would be
New-EventLog command found here

[MSDM New-eventLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-eventlog)

## Edit after more detail supplied.

Basic principle of what you want is to query the log file and write the lines found into a event log. This is done like the below:

```
#Get the content of the error log, gets the top 10 lines ONLY!!
$GetLog = Get-Content -Path D:\Errorlog.txt -totalcount 10 

#Now take the data found and write it to the event log under the source and log below
Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "My Application" -Eventid 1001 
-EntryType Error -Message "$Getlog" -Category 1
```

Comment: i need to display the log of the application in event log windows
myapplication.log ---> application event log windows

Comment: You'd need to execute it from your code / system where this event is coming from as an iteration of the event logging system
Or, run a scheduled tasks / job to detect new events
or, run a constant loop in powershell detecting updates